# On save add timestamp in attribute table?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, timestamp

I would like to add / update a timestamp value in a column of the attribute table whenever this attribute table is saved. Should I do it with an own python script or is there any in-built functionality which can perform this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using QGIS v2.18.x (or 2.99) you can set a default value expression. In your case the expression could be `now()`, which returns current date and time. That you get a valid timestamp might depend on your column type, I've tested it with a Text column. See https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog218/index.html#feature-client-side-default-field-values

Optionally, you can use the [AutoFields](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AutoFields/) plugin. [Here a video](https://vimeo.com/178984647) of your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was aware of this default value expression. But in my case it only triggers when I create a new object and I would like to update this value whenever I edit this object. But I will have a look in this AutoFields plugin!

Comment: The plugin was indeed the functionality I was searching for! THanks for that! Unfortunately it is not compatible with the QField application, which I am using, but perhaps I find a workaround to that.